# How can I echo a files last modified time in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code that echos if a file has been modified today or not.
How can I add so it can echo not only that the file was modified today, but also at what time?

Like for example "File modified today at %modifytime%".

```
@echo off
for %%F in (C:\temp\file.txt) do (for /F %%D in ("%%~tF") do (set mdate=%%D))
for /F "tokens=2" %%D in ('date/t') do set cdate=%%D
if "%date%"=="%mdate%" echo File modified today
if not "%date%"=="%mdate%" echo File not modified today
```

Comment: See the [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and also [arguments](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html); you will find there is a modifier `~t` that lets return the last modification date and time of a file; add the option `"delims="` to the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to get both date and time, or use `"tokens=2"` to get the time only (most probably, depending on your locale and region settings). By the way: you can combine the two `if` statements to one: `if "%date%"=="%mdate%" (echo File modified today) else (echo File not modified today)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an quick idea using the built-in **`ForFiles`** command:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\temp\file.txt") Do (If Not "%__CD__%"=="%%~dpA" PushD "%%~dpA"
    ForFiles /M "%%~nxA" /D 0 /C^
    "Cmd /C Echo @File was modified today0x09@fDate @fTime"2>Nul||(
    Echo "%%A" not modified today))
Pause
```

As with your example, this idea allows you to replace the single file between the parentheses on line 3 with:

- **`*`** to output for every file in the current directory.
- **`"C:\temp\file1.txt" "C:\somewhere\fileZ.exe"`** to output for multiple known files.
  *Special Note: The use of **`PushD`** without a **`PopD`** may restrict the number of different directories; if using this option please use sparingly.*

For safety, I recommend your entries between those parentheses be double quoted.

Comment: Sweet, can I output this to a txt like:

`@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\temp\file.txt") Do (If Not "%__CD__%"=="%%~dpA" PushD "%%~dpA"
    ForFiles /M "%%~nxA" /D 0 /C^
    "Cmd /C Echo @File was modified today0x09@fDate @fTime >> "C:\temp\result.txt""2>Nul||(
    Echo "%%A" not modified today >> "C:\temp\result.txt"))
Pause`

It feels wrong though.

Comment: Made it work with:

`@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\temp\file.txt") Do (If Not "%__CD__%"=="%%~dpA" PushD "%%~dpA"
    ForFiles /M "%%~nxA" /D 0 /C^
    "Cmd /C Echo @File was modified today0x09@fDate @fTime"2>Nul >> result.txt ||(
    Echo "%%A" not modified today >> result.txt ))
Pause`

Thank you.